# Create a new email account from php script on dovecot/postfix

Tags: php, email, imap, postfix-mta, dovecot

I'd like to make a page to allow people to create new email accounts on a dovecot/postfix server (via imap).

I've seen the php functions `imap_open` and `imap_createmailbox`, but these functions don't create accounts, it only creates a new directory :/
 (and you need the login/password of an existing account to use `imap_open`...)

So I'd like to know if it's possible to do this :).

### Edit

I'm adding this because my previous message wasn't specific enough. 
I need a front page to allow the users to register a new mailbox and to check if their wanted mail alias is free or not. That's why most of the web-based admin are not good for me. I don't want the end-users to see the admin panel.

Comment: System services often use system accounts (as in: `/etc/passwd`), although that may depend on the setup, in any case, you need to use some shell command or modify system files/databases. There are no PHP functions that will do this for you... There are already many web-based solutions for this, I would recommend using one of those, instead of making your own.

Comment: take a look at http://vmm.localdomain.org/

Comment: Sure I could use a web-based solution but unfortunately I need it to be developped in php :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By *default* postfix & dovecot get their users from the system. This is `/etc/passwd` on a UNIX/Linux box.

Managing this from a PHP script is possible, but not too pretty.

- You can use [`posix_getpwnam`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-getpwnam.php) to check if a username exists, and get information about this user.
- Adding users is best done with `useradd(8)` on Linux. You will need to use `exec()` to launch this shell utility. Example usage might be:

  ```
    $pw = crypt($_POST['password'], '$6$1234567890123456'); # This should be 16 characters of random salt
    exec(sprintf('useradd --groups mailuser --no-user-group --shell nologin --password %s', escapeshellarg($pw));
  ```

I wouldn't really recommend this, though.

What I would recommend, is storing your users in a SQL database, such as PostgreSQL, MySQL, or SQLite. This is fairly easy to set up, and on the PHP side all you have to do is add/remove/update rows on the database. This is probably the best solution since it's not too complex, yet still fairly flexible.
The [postfix](http://www.postfix.org/documentation.html) page has a few "HOWTO's" on the subject, and [so does dovecot](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Authentication).

Aa a final option, there's LDAP. LDAP is more complex, but arguably 'better' & more flexible. PHP has a [LDAP](https://www.php.net/ldap) interface.

Comment: Beware you open a huge set of security issues by doing account management from a web server.

Comment: @Max Why would this be insecure? You could, obviously, make it insecure, but that's the case for  *any* account management system.

Answer (score 4):

Well. The answer depends on where the list of user accounts for dovecot and postfix is stored on your server. I.e. where do dovecot and postfix retrieve user accounts from. I.e. dovecot and postfix *do not maintain their own lists of user accounts*, they just take some existing list. For example, several years ago I had configured dovecot and postfix so that they *were taking list of user accounts (and respective e-mail addresses, storage paths, etc) from MySQL database*. In such implementation it would be enough just to insert several records in that MySQL database for adding new email account.

I don't know how dovecot and postfix are configured on your server. Maybe they are just using system user accounts (then you need to add user account with `useradd`/`adduser`), maybe they retrieve user account list from LDAP (then you need to insert users into LDAP), or just from plain config file (then you need to edit config file).

Comment: how can we setup   dovecot/postfix so they retrieve users from  a DBMS like MySQL or MongoDB

Comment: About Postfix: [Postfix and PostgreSQL](http://www.postfix.org/PGSQL_README.html). About Dovecot: [Virtual users in Dovecot](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/VirtualUsers), [Dovecot and SQL database](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/AuthDatabase/SQL). Also in [Dovecot HowTo](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/HowTo) there's section about how to bind all three together: search the [Dovecot HowTo](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/HowTo) page for the word "PostgreSQL".